# change columns name from strings in a row

Tags: python, pandas

Let s assume we have a data frame(1000 rows and 100 columns) and it is in the following form

```
      unnamed : 1      unnamed : 2        unnamed : 3        unnamed : 4          unnamed : 5       ... unnamed : 99
0     Names            Total players
1     (empty cell)      male               female            age< 18(string)      age>18(string)                            
2     Team 1              5                  2                   4                    3
3     Team 2           
...
999
```

And i want it in a form

```
     Names    Total players male    Total players female  Total players age< 18(string)  Total players age> 18(string)
0    Team 1             5                2                         4                               3               
1    Team 2          
...
999
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
x = df.loc[0].dropna().to_list() //first row
y = df.loc[1].dropna().to_list() // second row

df.columns = x[:1] + [f'{x[1]} {col}' for col in y] // creating new columns using x and y

df = df.loc[2:].reset_index(drop=True)

print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
    Names Total players male Total players female Total players age< 18(string) Total players age>18(string)
0  Team 1                  5                    2                             4                            3
1  Team 2                NaN                  NaN                           NaN                          NaN
```

Comment: How about using `map()` rather than loop? For that instead of using `x` we would have `map(lambda x: 'Total players ' + x,y)`. What do you say?

Comment: @JenilDave we need to convert result of map to list

Comment: Yes, that goes without saying.

Comment: @JenilDave for your info it is list comprehension  not for loop

Comment: Thanks but I know that!

Comment: Hey thank you all for the input. I tried the way @deadshot said but i get the following error ``` Length mismatch: Expected axis has 99 elements, new values have 100 elements.```  Even though x and y have the same size. I m trying to figure out why that happens

Comment: it's because your dataframe has only 99 columns but the new_column length is 100

Comment: Hey @deadshot thank you for the help and the immediate response. Yes i understood what the error means! I meant i m trying to see how i can fix it!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
# rename columns
df.columns = df.iloc[0]
# delete the first row
df = df.iloc[1:]
```

Comment: your answer not give the expected output

Comment: I have added a line that deletes the first row as well.

Comment: @deadshot - I think it does. Let's wait for Alex

Comment: No column names should be like this `Names    Total players male    Total players female  Total players age< 18(string)  Total players age> 18(string)`

Comment: i tried df.iloc[0]+df.iloc[1] but the problem is it doesn t leave any space between the words. How can i add space? I tried df.iloc[0]+ '  '  +df.iloc[1] . Also it doesn t add the name of total players to the rest cells that needed(for the age columns i mean)

Comment: Pls explain better what you want and why the solution I provided does not do the job